# How to change to a ValueEventListener that i can remove?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I have a Firebase valueEvent listener:

```
 questions.orderByChild("CategoryID").equalTo(categoryID)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Question ques = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                        Common.questionList.add(ques);
                    }
                    //Random List
                    Collections.shuffle(Common.questionList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

As its best practice to have an object that can be attached and removed, i want to change the code to a ValueEventListener object. I did the following:

```
mQuestionsListener = questions.orderByChild("CategoryID").equalTo(categoryID)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Question ques = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                        Common.questionList.add(ques);
                    }
                    //Random List
                    Collections.shuffle(Common.questionList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    questions.addValueEventListener(mQuestionsListener);
```

but is not working.
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already added a listener here `questions.addValueEventListener(mQuestionsListener);`, then you need to declare a new `ValueEventListener()`:

```
ValueEventListener mQuestionsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Question ques = postSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                        Common.questionList.add(ques);
                    }
                    //Random List
                    Collections.shuffle(Common.questionList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes but the listener is in questions.orderByChild("CategoryID").equalTo(categoryID). If i use your code and add questions.addValueEventListener(mQuestionsListener); will not work.Right?

Comment: `mQuestionsListener ` is of type ValueEventListener you need to do like this: `questions.orderByChild("CategoryID").equalTo(categoryID).addValueEventListener(mQuestionsListener);`